# get view from libGDX application Android

Tags: java, android, view, libgdx

I am making a LibGDX app, and I need to get the view to put to an Android app.
Here is the code to get the view:

```
package jangkoo.game.shadowfiend.android;

import jangkoo.game.shadowfiend.ShadowFiendGame;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
public class LibGdx extends AndroidApplication {
    private static final String TAG = "LibGDx";
    public View view;
    Bundle savedInstanceState;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(savedInstanceState == null)
        this.savedInstanceState = getIntent().getExtras();
        Log.e(TAG,savedInstanceState + "");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        view = initializeForView(new ShadowFiendGame(), config);

    }
    public LibGdx(){
        onCreate(new Bundle());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        }
}
```

And I want to get the libGDX.view from this,for a class that doesn't extend AndroidApplication.

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    interstitialAd = new IntestialAds(this);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    libGdx = new LibGdx();
    Log.e(TAG,libGdx.view + "");
}
```

However, the onCreate function has nullpointer exception. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wrong way of working with Android views in libgdx project. You should place all logic which works with view on `LibGdx extends AndroidApplication` class and if you want to get access to this logic from another class you should create `Interface` which will be transferred to your main `Game` class. Such way you will be able to get access to your 'Android specific' logic in any place. Look at this guide for more details - [Interfacing with platform specific code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code)

Comment: I want the begin layout will be native code, then button press will call initializeForView to get the Game view. But it looks like i need to call it on onCreate. How can I do that? Is that i need to create all screen by LibGdx?

Comment: 1. Call initializeForView in your LibGdx onCreate. 2. Add it to your game, but set it not visible. 3. Put functions which you will call on button press in interface. 4. Implement interface in LibGdx class. 4. Now you can call it where you want for example you can create two functions showAd() and hideAd(). You have the same example here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

Comment: like this how can I get some values in the main Game, like the state over to switch to other native code screen?

Comment: You will just create one more function in interface, which will return you state and then other function with natvie code also from interface. The main idea is: to have as less as possible platform specific code.